# Move records from repeating rows to columns with Excel and VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 70,000 rows of data and two columns (Field,Data) which repeats every 50-100 rows (Record). I would like to write something that searches for the values based on "Field Text" (I'm only interested in about 5 fields) and paste the value into a new worksheet with rows as records and columns as fields.  The first field I'm searching for will need to indicate new row/record.

My first attempt at this failed, and I've found little help on the forums. Although it looks like maybe a pivot table could do this?

Visual of what I'd like to do:
[Example](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7ouV8OekEmwaXRINU5LTy0waUU/edit?usp=sharing)

EDIT:

I got the result I wanted but my do until "END" isnt catching. I do have "END" in the last cell of the data. Also, I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this, any advice? Thanks!

```
Sub TracePull()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

i = 1
j = 1

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A1").Select

Do Until Range("A" & i) = "END"

Do Until ActiveCell = "OTDRFilename"
    i = i + 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A" & i).Activate
Loop

If ActiveCell = "OTDRFilename" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("B" & i).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & j + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValue
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A" & i).Select
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1
'Else
'    i = i + 1
End If

Range("A" & i).Select

Do Until ActiveCell = "OTDRSpan length"
    i = i + 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A" & i).Activate
Loop

If ActiveCell = "OTDRSpan length" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("B" & i).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValue
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A" & i).Select
    i = i + 1
End If

Range("A" & i).Select

Do Until ActiveCell = "OTDRSpan loss"
    i = i + 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A" & i).Activate
Loop

If ActiveCell = "OTDRSpan loss" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("B" & i).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValue
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A" & i).Select
    i = i + 1
End If

Range("A" & i).Select

Do Until ActiveCell = "OTDRAverage loss"
    i = i + 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A" & i).Activate
Loop

If ActiveCell = "OTDRAverage loss" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("B" & i).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValue
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A" & i).Select
    i = i + 1
End If

Range("A" & i).Select

Do Until ActiveCell = "OTDRSpan ORL"
    i = i + 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A" & i).Activate
Loop

If ActiveCell = "OTDRSpan ORL" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("B" & i).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValue
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A" & i).Select
    i = i + 1
End If

Range("A" & i).Select

Do Until ActiveCell = "OTDRWavelength"
    i = i + 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A" & i).Activate
Loop

If ActiveCell = "OTDRWavelength" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("B" & i).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValue
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A" & i).Select
    i = i + 1
End If

i = i + 1
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A" & i).Select

Range("A" & i).Select

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You will have better luck if you post your code. We can't read your mind and find out what your code that failed was.

Comment: At the time I had no code to provide. Now I've got a start, and thinking that maybe Do Loops will be the best way to rearrange my data. I'm still coming up short though, as I am not familiar with how to "move" around the cells through vba. Thanks!

Comment: Try counting the rows and starting at the bottom iterating up the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main problem is incrementing i twice (which passes 'END' cell) at the bottom of your code.

One way to make it more readable is by using select case.  Also, you can speed up the code by assigning the value directly (without copy paste) and by turning off screen updating since you have 70,000 rows.  Those things will improve performance considerably.

```
Sub TracePull()

  ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long

  i = 1
  j = 1

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A1").Select

    Do Until Range("A" & i) = "END"
      Select Case ActiveCell.Text
        Case "OTDRFilename"
          ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & j + 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("B" & i).Value

        Case "OTDRSpan length"
          ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & j).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("B" & i).Value

        Case "OTDRSpan loss"
          ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("B" & i).Value

        Case "OTDRAverage loss"
          ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & j).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("B" & i).Value

        Case "OTDRSpan ORL"
          ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & j).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("B" & i).Value

        Case "OTDRWavelength"
          ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & j).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("B" & i).Value
        End Select

      i = i + 1
      j = j + 1
      ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trace").Range("A" & i).Select
    Loop
    ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

You might also want to consider defining the workbook and worksheet rather than relying upon activesheet.  In addition, the code with break if someone forget to have 'END' entered in the last cell, so maybe just get last cell used instead of looking for 'END'

```
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim wskA As Worksheet
  Dim wskB As Worksheet

  wb = ActiveWorkbook
  wskA = wb.Sheets("Trace")
  wskB = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

  numofrows = wskA.Offset(wskA.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
  wskA.Range("A1").Select

    Do Until i > numofrows
      Select Case ActiveCell.Text
        Case "OTDRFilename"
          wskB.Range("A" & j + 1).Value = wskA.Range("B" & i).Value
```

Comment: Thanks! A lot of information here I need to learn/understand before I use. Appreciate the comments!